# how to change content of an app

Tags: android, ios, dynamic

First of all, i am a webdeveloper. I have no knowledge of creating an app for Android or Aplle devices. But i was looking for a way to convert my responsive webpage to an app. And Google brought me to appypie. I tried it and indeed, it created an app based on my website. 
But there is one problem now: I can easily change the content of the website.
I have to change the prices on the website every month.
But how does this work in an app? How can i change the content of an existing app?
I have really no idea how to handle with this. Is it possible or not?

Answer (score 1):

best way to make an app for website is using `webView`
you can enable java script have a progress bar and maybe a address bar
and it loads your website each time activity starts up
I already have a complete code check it

the activity

```
public class SamaActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

WebView webView;
ProgressBar sama_ProgressBar;
TextView sama_url;

@SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_sama);

    sama_url = findViewById(R.id.sama_url);
    sama_ProgressBar = findViewById(R.id.sama_ProgressBar);

    webView = findViewById(R.id.sama_webview);
    webView.setInitialScale(100);
    webView.setWebChromeClient(
            new WebChromeClient() {
                @Override
                public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress) {
                    if (progress < 100 && sama_ProgressBar.getVisibility() == ProgressBar.GONE) {
                        sama_ProgressBar.setVisibility(ProgressBar.VISIBLE);
                    }

                    sama_ProgressBar.setProgress(progress);
                    if (progress == 100) {
                        sama_ProgressBar.setVisibility(ProgressBar.GONE);
                    }
                }
            }
    );
    webView.setWebViewClient(
            new WebViewClient() {
                @Override
                public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                    if (Uri.parse(url).getHost().equals("sama.fums.ac.ir")) {
                        return false;
                    }
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
                    startActivity(intent);
                    return true;
                }

                @Override
                public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
                    super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);

                    Log.d("WebView", "your current url when webpage loading.." + url);
                    sama_url.setText(url);
                }

                @Override
                public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                    Log.d("WebView", "your current url when webpage loading.. finish" + url);
                    super.onPageFinished(view, url);
                    sama_url.setText(url);
                }
            }
    );
    webView.loadUrl("http://sama.fums.ac.ir/samaweb/Login.aspx");

    WebSettings settings = webView.getSettings();
    settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    settings.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
}

@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) && webView.canGoBack()) {
        webView.goBack();
        return true;
    }

    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

}

and the layout

```
<LinearLayout
android:orientation="vertical"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#d7d7d7"
tools:context=".activities.SamaActivity">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:background="@color/primary_light"
    android:layout_margin="3dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/sama_url"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

</LinearLayout>

<ProgressBar
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
    android:id="@+id/sama_ProgressBar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="5dp"
    android:indeterminate="true"
     />

<WebView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/sama_webview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
     />
```

in case you want to use this sample just change address url and main domain